# How do I properly shutdown and dump a Redis server with Foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, foreman, procfile

I have a Procfile that I use with Foreman to start my local redis and webrick server:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
redis: redis-server config/redis.development.conf
```

I connect to Redis using a named socket that is defined in the configuration like this:

```
unixsocket /tmp/redis-APPNAME.sock
```

Everything works fine in Rails, but when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate Foreman in the terminal, the Redis DB is not dumped. The Redis server is `terminated by SIGINT` this way. So, whenever I restart the Foreman stack I get old Redis data.

Is there a way to tell Foreman to use the proper SHUTDOWN on Redis that will also dump the database? Or should I modify the Redis config to persist data all the time in development?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [wrapper script](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Custom-Signals) to send [SIGTERM](http://redis.io/topics/signals) instead?

Comment: If sending `SIGTERM` still does not cause Redis to save the dump file, call the [shutdown](http://redis.io/commands/shutdown) command: `redis-cli shutdown save`.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using Append-only File persistance on my development laptop for Redis instances. To turn it on you just have to add `appendonly yes` to your redis config. I left the fsync option to 1 second.

This way I always get persisted data when I terminate Foreman and switch to another project.

More details about Redis persistance options here: http://redis.io/topics/persistence